# Best practice for deprecating functionality in a JavaScript library

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a Rails add-on that includes Javascript that has API methods intended for use by application developers, and I'm wondering what I should do when I deprecate part of that functionality as the code evolves.

If this were Ruby code, I would write a message to STDOUT the first time a deprecated method was called. so the developer will notice ASAP.  Perhaps, in JavaScript, I should check for the existence of `console`, and write a message to `console.log()`?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, maybe using `console.warn()` instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: You should also watch out that console.log sometimes breaks code in older browsers that don't support the console.

Comment: Arend -- That's why I would check for the existence of `console` before trying to use it.

Comment: Frédéric -- Thanks.  I wasn't aware of the other console methods besides `.log`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe an answer to this topic will be somewhat opinionated.

Nevertheless I would follow the way outlined by [this](https://css-tricks.com/approaches-to-deprecating-code-in-javascript/) blogpost:

> 1. Add a @deprecated JSDoc flag.
> 2. Mention the version that the method was deprecated.
> 3. Figure out a timeframe for when this method will be deleted, including which version it will take place. Otherwise, based on my
>    experience, it stays forever
> 4. Use comments liberally to explain the implementation for the benefit of other developers or your future self. This is extremely
>    useful if your use-case is writing a library that others use as a
>    dependency for their work.
> 5. Add a console warning message that indicates that the function is deprecated.